# google login via expo browser failing on redirect?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

---

I'm attempting to log into my app via a `WebView` that loads my website's auth login page.

I am currently testing the Google login and everything seems to be going well, allowing me to enter my email and password, then also allowing me to do 2FA, however after this last step and before it kicks me back to the app/closes the browser, it shows the message:

[image]

I'm wondering what might be going wrong at this point - Whether the url it is trying to kick back to is incorrect, or something else?

```
const load = async (url) => {
    authUrl = url.replace(
      encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('my-app://)),
      encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('my-app://return')),
    );

    try {
      Linking.addEventListener('url', handleUrl);

      const res = await openAuthSessionAsync(authUrl);

      if (!res?.url) // do something else

      // Do something with the res after it returns
    } catch (e) {
      // Something to catch here
    }
  }

const handleUrl = ({url}) => {
  // Do some stuff

  Linking.removeEventListener('url', handleUrlEvent);

  // do more stuff
}

const onShouldStartLoadWithRequest = ({url: loadUrl}) => {
  if (loadUrl.indexOf('my-app://return') === 0) {
    // do storage and other good stuff
    return false;
  }

  // Handle Google auth url here
  if (loadUrl.indexOf('external?provider=Google') > -1) {
    load(loadUrl);
    return false;
  }
}

return (
  <WebView
    source={{ uri: authUrl }}
    onShouldStartLoadWithRequest={onShouldStartLoadWithRequest}
    originWhitelist={['http', 'https', 'my-app']}
    onHttpError={(e) => console.log(e)}
    onError={(e) => console.log(e)}
  />
);
```

Upon clicking the `ok` button on the popup warning and then the `cancel` button on the auth browser window, I can then see the following log printed from the `load()` function:

> {"error": "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.AuthenticationServices.WebAuthenticationSession error 1.)", "type": "cancel", "url": null}

along with an unhandled promise rejection warning...

Answer (score 1):

When you configured Google login in Google's site, you had to give Google a redirect URL. If you are testing in Expo Go, the redirect URL should be something like `exp://127.0.0.1:8081/--/`, not `my-app://`. To find your exact redirect URL, run `console.log(Linking.createURL() + '/--/')`. Anything after the `/--/` is the file path. For example, `/--/myPage.js` should link to `myPage.js`, assuming `myPage.js` is in the root directory of the project.

Your `app.json` should have this:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "scheme": "my-unique-app-name"
  }
}
```

This will send web searches of `my-unique-app-name://` to your app after it is built and submitted to the Apple App Store or Google Play Store. Note that the value for `"scheme"` shouldn't literally be `"my-app"`.

Google lets you add multiple redirect URLs. You can add your `exp://` and `my-unique-app-name://` URLs.

In your app, you can use `Linking.createURL()` to automatically determine if the app is running in Expo Go or a built iOS or Android app and build a corresponding URL. See more [here](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/#creating-urls).

Comment: The Google Cloud API Credentials where you add Authorized redirect URIs gives the warning "Invalid Redirect: must use either http or https as the scheme." when entering anything like "host.exp.exponent://127.0.0.1:8081/--/". Do you know anyway around this?

Comment: @totallytotallyamazing Something isn't right there. http or https will open in the device's default web browser. Try typing host.exp.exponent://127.0.0.1:8081/--/ in your mobile device's browser and searching. If it doesn't take you to your mobile app, Google won't be able to use that URI to redirect to your app.